# How to upgrade java compiler - different problem

Tags: upgrade, java, compiling

After the most recent automatic software update, java 7 on 14.04 no longer works. The initial problem is the same as that described at "How to upgrade Java compiler".

Here's the message we got:

```
warning: Blabla.class: major version 52 is newer than 51, the highest major version supported by this compiler.

it is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
```

The solution given there was suggested after the questioner gave the outputs of "javac -version" and "java -version" - these two were not the same.

In my case, the output of these queries appears to be the same. Here they are, in case I'm missing something:

javac -version

javac 1.7.0_95

java -version

java version "1.7.0_95"

OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.4) (7u95-2.6.4-0ubuntu0.14.04.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.95-b01, mixed mode)

executing

"sudo update-alternatives --config javac"

showed three alternatives. I tried all three, and none worked. I then completely removed all java from the system (following the instructions at "How to completely uninstall java".) I then installed java 7 from the Oracle site. While the original error message still occurs and I can't run a compiled program, there is now only one alternative after

"sudo update-alternatives --config javac"

it says:
There is only one alternative in link group javac (providing /usr/bin/javac): /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac
Nothing to configure.

For completeness, here is what happens when I try to compile/run a program that was working just before the automatic update:

lanzcc@ubuntu910:~/recruit$ javac ReadProgram.java

warning: ./Program.class: major version 52 is newer than 51, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
  It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
1 warning

lanzcc@ubuntu910:~/recruit$ java ReadProgram

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Program : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:803)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2625)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2866)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1676)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)
lanzcc@ubuntu910:~/recruit$

Any ideas?

THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED

There was, among the various class files, one that had not been compiled since the software upgrade. I knew all the others were being recompiled, but I just didn't notice this one. Thus it had a non-matching compiler tag.

Sorry.